# how to set current month as default value on simple parameter on pentaho cde?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I have a simple parameter where I should pass the first day of current month.
What should I write on property value?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom parameter, which allows you to set it to the return value of a Javascript function:

```
function(){
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getMonth() + 1;
}
```

When you load the dashboard the parameter will be calculated and will have an integer value between 1 and 12.

If you want the parameter to have as value the date string for day 1 of this month you can instead use

```
function(){
  var now = new Date();
  var y = now.getFullYear();
  var m = now.getMonth()+1;
  m = (m<10 ? '0' : '') + m;
  var d = '01';
  return y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
}
```

This will return the date as a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` for day 1 of the current month.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I tried with your second function, first of all, when I use getFullyear, it doesn't work at all (error processing etc). So I changed it to getYear(), then at least I don't have any error but when my dashboard is loaded at first, it doesn't work (my chart depending on selected month are not displayed) but when I select other months, it works. I don't understand at all.

Comment: sorry, there's a typo. it's getFullYear() (note the capital Y). I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the properties file cannot have a formula that will calculate on run time when you use the value.

What you can do instead, is in the beggining of your Job have a KTR that will set this variable for you.

You KTR should look something like this:

[image]

Set the parameter date_mois (exact same name) in your Root Job, and this variable will be passed down to subsequent KTR / JOB calls (This is default unless uncheked).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However I am on Ctools. I managed to get current month on PDI (just as you did) but not on Ctools...